# gae static directory html

Tags: html, google-app-engine

I am trying to use Google App Engine's app.yaml to automatically serve *.html files when it is requested.  So I have the following in my file structure:

```
-myapp
    -html (folder)
        -index.html
    -index.py
```

In my app.yaml I have:

```
handlers:
-url: /*\.html
static_dir: html

-url: /.*
script: index.app
```

However, when I run this on my browser localhost:8080/index.html, I get a 404 Not Found.
Why is it not routing to my index.html file?

Comment: I think it's something like `- url: /(.*\.html)` and `- static_files: html/\1`.

Comment: That worked, thanks!  Had to also add upload: to it too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is several ways you can do this type of thing depending on what you want exactly.  You can use a regex such as @hyperslug added if all you want is static content without any of the more advanced features.

You can set urls like so:

```
- url: /
  static_files: static/html/index.html
  upload: static/html/index.html
  secure: never
```

which allows you to set page security on a individual file basis if that is what you want.  Or you can combine regex with security such as:

```
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  secure: always
```

Remember that if your sharing the pages with public search engines treat http/https as 2 different links.  As well as with and without trailing /.